# Collection for groups

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

Is there a collection type that is just for groups?  Or is the only option out there a `List<IGrouping<Key, ItemType>>`?

Basically, I am wanting to do dictionary type things with the list, like `GroupList.ContainsKey(key)` and `GroupList.TryGetItems(key, out items)`, plus a few group related things like `GroupList.AddToGroup(key, Item)`.

Yes, I know I can write these myself as extension methods, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is something already out there for groups.

If not then I will "roll my own".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **group** records of yourRecordType by yourGroupingType and do 'Dictionary-Things' with it - why not gor for a `Dictionary` or a `SortedDictionary`?

```
Dictionary <yourGroupingType, List<yourRecordType > >
```

I think this will allow you all you need. Dictionary has a rich set of methods.

If you really only have key-value pairs, a simpler structure would do, but I don't see where the grouping would come in?

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try a `KeyValuePair`: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  They're wonderfully generic and make KV-related things much easier.  (for reference, I used these for a hashtable implementation I had to write for class.  Hash against the key and pull the value and you're done.  It's great.)

I recommend a list of them:

`List<KeyValuePair<String, Int32>> things = new List<KeyValuePair<String, Int32>>();`

Then you can do cool things like (LINQ):

```
from x in things
where x.Key == "me me me!"
select x
```